# SQL Server 2005 stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures, coalesce

I am writing a stored procedure to update a transaction table.

I will be updating one transaction type at a time (shipment, receipt or disposal)

If I'm updating shipment, I will pass in a value, and leave the other two blank.

How can I write a stored procedure so that it only updates the field when the value I'm passing in is not NULL (or 0, whichever is easier), and leave the others as they were?

Here is where I am now:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_UpdateTransaction] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    @ID int,
    @disposalID int,
    @shipID int,
    @recID int,
as
begin
   update tblX
   set
     disposalID = COALESCE(@disposalID, disposalID)
     receiptID = COALESCE(@recID, receiptID)
     shipmentID = COALESCE(@shipID,shipmentID)
   where ID = @sID 
END
```

`COALESCE` doesn't seem to work, as I keep getting errors, is there another function I can use to make this happen?

I'm getting:

> Incorrect syntax near 'receiptID'.

I don't see why :(

Thank you!

Comment: **What database system, what version??** Stored PRocs aren't portable between vendors, and aren't standardized enough by SQL standard committees for any meaningful "general" answer that works with every database system.....

Comment: no, you're using **Microsoft** SQL **Server** 2005. [SQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL) is a standard language, implemented by MS SQL Server, Oracle DBMS, IBM DB2, MySQL, PostgreSQL, Interbase... So, you should use this tag only for generic, vendor-independent questions.

Comment: huh? what tag? what are you talking about?

Comment: Stack Overflow uses tags (at the bottom of your post you see `sql` `sql-server` `stored-procedures` `coalesce` to indicate what products and/or categories a question belongs to.  If you improperly tag it you may get inappropriate answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason you are getting error could also be because you are missing `','` at end of each `set`.

```
update tblX
set
disposalID = COALESCE(@disposalID, disposalID),
receiptID = COALESCE(@recID, receiptID),
shipmentID = COALESCE(@shipID,shipmentID)
where ID = @sID
```

As an alternative, you can use [ISNULL()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184325.aspx) assuming you are using SQL server.

Comment: I changed it to ISNULL, but i keep getting: 

Incorrect syntax near 'receiptID'.

Comment: @xrum - it is because you are missing `','`. See my answer

Comment: Thank you! is there a difference if I use COALESCE or ISNULL? I looked it up online, they look the same..

Comment: @xrum - You should still be able to continue with COALESCE. As for your case, I dont think it makes any difference.

Answer (score 2):

what you can do is put each update statement inside an `IF` or a `CASE` statement. like:

```
IF @disposalid is not null:
     update tblX
     set disposalID = @disposalID
```

Answer (score 1):

did you try using `ISNULL ( check_expression , replacement_value )`